# Chrome changed the new tab page to a search bar. I want the "apps" new tab page back

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome just updated and the new tab page is now a Google search box above a grid of frequently accessed websites. The update also added an "Apps" bookmark to my bookmark toolbar. Clicking on the apps bookmark opens up what used to be the new tab page.

My question is, how can I get the old "new tab" page back?

Comment: I don't seem to have got the search box. Neither has any bookmark been added. Could you add a screenshot showing the change?

Comment: Its happening slowly.. My co-worker just got it now, but mine has Still not got the update. Thankfully I have pre-disabled this option to make sure I don't get the new 'new-tab-page'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Chrome
2. Enter chrome://flags/
3. Search for Instant Extended API
4. Disable it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I also read [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TNOHnCgXQvo) that disabling this feature could have performance benefits!

Answer (score 2):

Google seem to have removed the option to disable Instant Extended API (at least on Linux with Chrome 33 stable), so you might be stuck with it now.